# Route redirection is not working in 'verify.shopify' middleware in laravel shopify app with using "Kyon147/laravel-shopify" package

Tags: laravel, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am using `Kyon147/laravel-shopify` package for my laravel shopify app integration and I just found that in `verify.shopify` middleware custom routes are not working while I call the same routes outisde middleware and it's working fine.

I am using `Kyon147/laravel-shopify` package for my laravel shopify app integration and I just found that in `verify.shopify` middleware custom routes are not working while I call the same routes outisde middleware and it's working fine.

```
route::middleware(['verify.shopify'])->group(function () {
    // index page
    Route::get('/', [ConfigController::class, 'viewWelcome'])->name('home');

    // app - plan page
    Route::get('/plan', [ConfigController::class, 'viewPlans'])->name('plan');

});

Route::get('/privacy', [PagesController::class, 'privacyPolicyPage'])->name('pages.policy'); // contact support page
```

Here, `/privacy` route is completely working outside the middleware.

Package Name: `Kyon147/Laravel-shopify`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for this issue, and here's an answer for the `Kyon147\Laravel-Shopify` package.

If you are using the `blade` file then Replace `Route()` or `URL()` helpers to `URL::tokenRoute()` facades.

**For example:**

```
<a class="btn btn-sm py-3 w-sm-100 w-auto" href="{{ URL::tokenRoute('products') }}">Products </a>
```

If you are using the `controller` file then Replace `redirect()` or `redirect()->route()` helpers to `URL::tokenRoute()` facades.

```
public function home(Request $request)
{
    return view('home');  // return home page
}

public function dashboard(Request $request)
{
    return \Redirect::tokenRedirect('home');  // redirect to home route
}
```

This code is working for me

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are encountering an issue with the `verify.shopify` middleware from the Kyon147/Laravel-shopify package not working as expected for your custom routes. Let's troubleshoot this issue step by step:

1. **Middleware Configuration**: First, make sure you have properly configured the `verify.shopify` middleware in your Laravel application. Check your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file and ensure that the middleware is registered correctly. It should look something like this:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ...
        \Kyon147\LaravelShopify\Middleware\VerifyShopify::class,
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
];
```

2. **Middleware Parameters**: Verify if the `verify.shopify` middleware requires any additional parameters or configuration. Some middleware in Laravel may require specific settings or parameters to work correctly. Review the documentation of the Kyon147/Laravel-shopify package or the middleware itself to ensure it's configured correctly.
3. **Middleware Order**: Middleware order matters in Laravel. Ensure that the `verify.shopify` middleware is placed in the correct order within the middleware group. If it's supposed to run before your custom routes, make sure it appears before those routes in the `web` middleware group.
4. **Middleware Exemptions**: Check if the `verify.shopify` middleware has any route exemptions configured by default. It's possible that certain routes are excluded from the middleware's action.
5. **Middleware Logs/Debugging**: If the issue persists, consider adding some logging or debugging statements within the `verify.shopify` middleware to see if it's being triggered as expected. This can help you identify whether the middleware is the source of the problem.
6. **Package Documentation and Support**: If you're still facing issues after checking the above steps, consult the official documentation for the Kyon147/Laravel-shopify package. Additionally, check for any open issues or discussions on the package's GitHub repository or community forums. The package's author or other users may have encountered similar issues and could provide guidance or solutions.

Remember to clear your Laravel cache and routes using `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:clear` after making changes to your routes or middleware to ensure that the changes take effect.

By following these steps and consulting the package documentation and community support, you should be able to resolve the issue with your custom routes not working as expected within the `verify.shopify` middleware.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT